# When does the US president have to be 35 year old?

Tags: united-states, president, election-requirements

[The Constitution only says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_Two_of_the_United_States_Constitution#Clause_5:_Qualifications_for_office) that one needs to have "attained to the Age of thirty five Years" to be "eligible to the Office of President".

So, do you need to have your 35th birthday:

1. On or before the first primary/caucus?
2. On or before the nomination date?
3. On or before the election date?
4. On or before the date of the College of Electors vote?
5. On or before the date of taking the oath of office?
6. Or some other step/deadline that I've missed?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

While no 35-year old has ever become President, people at the minimum age have entered Congress. Jed Johnson, Jr. was elected at the age of 24 but turned 25 that December (before assuming office). In the Senate, Rush D. Holt, Sr. was elected at 29 and was 29 when he was supposed to assume office; he just *didn't* assume office until his 30th birthday a few months into his term.

That suggests the age limit only matters at the time of assuming office.

Comment: Some senators and representatives have been seated before attaining the minimum age, however, so to the extent that this precedent is applicable, it rather suggests that the president doesn't actually have to be 35.